# CSS - using large images as background (performance)

Tags: html, css

I have question about site performance. I have 4 large images (1920*500px) that need to be show on the home page in some kind of slider - user need to click for the next image to show up, it is not slide show.
When home page is loaded, only first image is being seen, and rest are need to be seen only at user request.
My question is next. Is it smart to create one large image (sprite) and use this as **background** (this images have focus on centar, and users which have display that supports this resolution can see the hole image, users that don't have that kind of display will see as much as they can) or to go with standard **img** tag, or there is some better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The advantage of using a sprite is that you are saving HTTP requests and preloading images (which is essential for responsive image rollovers, for instance).

In your case, I don't think sprites make any sense.  First, you are only saving three http requests (the first image is presumably visible when you load the page) and you are forcing every visitor to download these large images even if they aren't going to see them.

Comment: Well, that is the way I am thinking, but if I use **img** tags, it comes to same thing - all images will be loaded one at the time. Second, how can I cut images if user have display with resolution smaller then 1920px? This will be relatively easy to do with background, but then again user needs to load one big sprite.

Comment: Use multiple divs with different background images, or change the background image of a single div using javascript - don't use a sprite.

Comment: I guess that will be the best way it can be done. I can put rules for the divs that are not displayed at the end of the page, and it will not make user wait. Thanks for the idea :)

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure I understand what your asking, but if your always rendering one of the images,then it may be smart to just create a full screen background image like this. You can also change the background image with js when necessary

```
<style>
html
{ 
  background: url("your image") no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity:1;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the class with jQuery.

```
.bg-1 { background: url("your image") no-repeat center center fixed; }
.bg-2 { background: url("your image 2") no-repeat center center fixed; }
.bg-3 { background: url("your image 3") no-repeat center center fixed; }
```